# Can't match the right function

Tags: erlang

Here's my codes:

```
-record(user,{id,name,group,age}).

adult_section(U=#user{})  when U#user.age  >=18   -> "allowed";

adult_section(_)    ->  "no permission".
```

it can be worked with:

```
>records_new:adult_section(#user{id=1,name='Ray',group=admin,age=10}).
  output:  "no permission"
```

but when  I try this:

```
> records_new:adult_section(#user{}).
  "allowed"
```

I didn't give the user's age in the second order, why it can be worked, why is not `"no permission"`.

Comment: You should *always specify default values* for records. Always. `undefined` is a value that will almost always cause unexpected results if you just run along and think that Erlang is like Python or Javascript (or whatever). Typespecs and sane defaults are critical for unsurprising code -- Erlang actually makes this both visually appealing *and* very readable. That said, @Dogbert's answer is exactly correct: atoms compare as higher values than all integers, so `undefined >= 18` is always `true`.

Answer (score 6):

Since your record does not have a default value for `age`, if you create the record without specifying a value for `age`, it defaults to the atom `undefined`.

```
1> #user{}.
#user{id = undefined,name = undefined,group = undefined,
      age = undefined}
```

In Erlang, atoms compare greater than integers:

```
2> undefined > 18.
true
3> foo > 100000000.
true
```

If you specify a default value of age to be e.g. `0`, your function works as you expect:

```
-record(user,{id,name,group,age = 0}).
```

```
1> #user{}.
#user{id = undefined,name = undefined,group = undefined,
      age = 0}
2> a:adult_section(#user{}).
"no permission"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [Dogbert answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46501442/1135337).  His explanation is spot-on.

I would like to only add that you could protect yourself from such "bad-data" injection by expanding your guard.

```
adult_section(U=#user{}) when 
    is_integer(U#user.age) andalso
    U#user.age  >=18   -> 
  "allowed";
```